# Merge two images in Android (background of 1st image and text of 2nd image with blur effect)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two images?
How can I show 2nd image on the top of 1st image in android(background of 2nd image must be visible and text of first image should be blur)

In other words, I want to use background of first image and text of 2nd image with blur effect

---

I have also attached two sample images 
I am using Android Studio 1.3.2

[image: 1st image]

[image: 2nd image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FrameLayout` for the container. Now, put both `ImageView` inside this `FrameLayout` and adjust its alpha value. So, your layout structure will look like this

```
FrameLayout (Container)
|__ImageView1 (Background)
|__ImageView2 (Text)
```

For the blur effect, you could use any Android image processing libraries out there in the internet.

Comment: Either set the background of the frame layout to be the first image, or just add an imageview with match parent for both height and width. I think it makes more sense to set the background of the Parent frame layout to be your first image

Answer (score -1):

Create bitmap of both image and mearge it using Canvas

```
   ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          Drawable drawableFore = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foreg);
          Drawable drawableBack = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backg);

          Bitmap bitmapFore = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableFore).getBitmap();
          Bitmap bitmapBack = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableBack).getBitmap();

          Bitmap scaledBitmapFore = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapFore, 35, 35, true);
          Bitmap scaledBitmapBack = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapBack, 45, 45, true);

          Bitmap combineImages = overlay(scaledBitmapBack, scaledBitmapFore);

          image.setImageBitmap(combineImages);
```

overlay method is here..

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
 try
 {
   Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(),  bmp1.getConfig());
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
   return bmOverlay;
 } catch (Exception e)
 {
    // TODO: handle exception
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
 }
}
```